# Why does SuperTuxKart use so much more processing power when running via RDP?

Tags: cpu-usage, xrdp

I want to play a game of SuperTuxKart with a friend over LAN. For technical reasons, they're playing the game over RDP instead of installing it themselves.

While *just on the menu*, my SuperTuxKart is using 15% of my CPU, but *theirs* is using 60%+. Why does connecting over RDP cause SuperTuxKart to use so much more CPU processing power?

Comment: @StephenKitt Not sure, but LXTask said that the SuperTuxKart process _itself_ was using the CPU. (SuperTuxKart was running on my machine, but they were connecting to my machine over RDP.)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread “theirs” as “their CPU”, not “their SuperTuxKart”.

Comment: If your friend starts STK from a terminal inside their RDP session (so that they can see the log messages), is there anything about GLSL? The difference could be that your instance is running with OpenGL, but theirs isn’t (although I thought STK *required* OpenGL).